# saving content of a buffer to a struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I would like to transfer a content of a buffer, which stores the data from an incoming message on a serial port, to a struct type so that I can use the element of the struct to pull out the data I need.

The struct, for example, look like this:

```
struct myStruct_t
{
    bool bool1;
    bool bool2;
    bool bool3;
    bool bool4;
    uint8_t _8bit;
    uint16_t _16bit;
    uint32_t _32bit;
    bool bool5;
    bool bool6;
    bool bool7;
    bool bool8;
};

struct myStruct_t myStruct = {0};
```

and the data I want to store is in this buffer:

```
uint8_t exampleValue[] = {{0xB1, 0xAB, 0x94, 0xF1, 0xA2, 0xB3, 0xC3}};
```

I try the below code but it is not successful

```
    uint8_t *pMyStruct = &myStruct.bool1;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(struct myStruct_t); i++) {
        *pMyStruct++ = exampleValue[i];
    }

    printf("bool1: %d\n\r", myStruct.bool1);
    printf("bool2: %d\n\r", myStruct.bool2);
    printf("bool3: %d\n\r", myStruct.bool3);
    printf("bool4: %d\n\r", myStruct.bool4);
```

the result for the above code is :

```
bool1: 177
bool2: 0
bool3: 0
bool4: 0
```

The expected result should be:

```
bool1: 1
bool2: 0
bool3: 1
bool4: 1
```

Comment: In the first iteration `pMyStruct` points to `bool1` and `exampleValue[0]` is `0xB1` or `177` in decimal. So why would you expect it to print  just `1`? I dont know why the others would print `0` though (which it does not on my machine). And what stops you from using `memcpy()`?

Comment: bool is the worst possible choice for binary transfer

Comment: You need to extract (demarhsall) each field from your input buffer.  You need to figure how the data is mapped (big- or little-indian) so is 0x01 & 0xB1 bool1 or is it  part of _8bit?

Comment: _t is reserved name space.

Comment: What is `bool` and `sizeof(bool)` on your machines? Better to use an explicit type such as `uint8_t`

Comment: `uint8_t *pMyStruct = &myStruct.bool1` is incompatible types.

Comment: `*pMyStruct++ = ...` will assign a value to the next byte (as it's a uint8_t *) so assigns a byte.  I would expect this to be undefined behavior (as you use address of a bool; and I don't think the compiler guarantees your struct is laid out without padding between fields).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use bool as bool is not a bit.

The solution below is not portable but gcc and clang are consistent and the behaviour of bitfields is well-defined in those implementations. Use `memcpy` instead of manual copying.

```
struct myStruct_t
{
    uint64_t bool1 : 1;
    uint64_t bool2 : 1;
    uint64_t bool3 : 1;
    uint64_t bool4 : 1;
    uint64_t bit8  : 8;
    uint64_t bit16 : 16;
    uint64_t bit32 : 32;
    uint64_t bool5 : 1;
    uint64_t bool6 : 1;
    uint64_t bool7 : 1;
    uint64_t bool8 : 1;
};

uint8_t exampleValue[8] = {0xB1, 0xAB, 0x94, 0xF1, 0xA2, 0xB3, 0xC3};

struct myStruct_t str;

memcpy(&str, exampleValue, sizeof(str));
```

Comment: You have 1 byte of garbage in `str` because it is 8 bytes and `exampleValue` is 7.

Comment: @FiddlingBits good counting, but not anymore

Comment: the above code gives me these results: bool1: 0x01, bool2: 0x00, bool3: 0x00, bool4: 0x00, bit8: 0xBB, bit16: 0x194A, bit32: 0xF194ABB1, bool5: 0x01, bool6: 0x01, bool7: 0x01, bool8: 0x01. It seems starting at bit32 it copy the first 4 bytes of the buffer, which is incorrect, and causing the follow bool to be incorrect as well.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to believe a `bool` is 1-bit.  This is not the case.  On my machine it is 8-bits.  If you want `bool1`, etc, to be 1-bit you should use bit fields.  For example:

```
struct myStruct
{
    uint8_t bool1 : 1;
    uint8_t bool2 : 1;
    uint8_t bool3 : 1;
    uint8_t bool4 : 1;
    uint8_t bool5 : 1;
    uint8_t bool6 : 1;
    uint8_t bool7 : 1;
    uint8_t bool8 : 1;
    uint8_t _8bit;
    uint16_t _16bit;
    uint32_t _32bit;
}
```

With this you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct myStruct
{
    uint8_t bool1 : 1;
    uint8_t bool2 : 1;
    uint8_t bool3 : 1;
    uint8_t bool4 : 1;
    uint8_t bool5 : 1;
    uint8_t bool6 : 1;
    uint8_t bool7 : 1;
    uint8_t bool8 : 1;
    uint8_t _8bit;
    uint16_t _16bit;
    uint32_t _32bit;
};

int main(int, char**) {
    struct myStruct s;
    uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)&s;
    uint8_t exampleValue[] = {0xB1, 0xAB, 0x94, 0xF1, 0xA2, 0xB3, 0xC3, 0xDE};
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(struct myStruct));
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(exampleValue); i++)
        p[i] = exampleValue[i];
    printf("%u\n", s.bool1);
    printf("%u\n", s.bool2);
    printf("%u\n", s.bool3);
    printf("%u\n", s.bool4);
    printf("%u\n", s.bool5);
    printf("%u\n", s.bool6);
    printf("%u\n", s.bool7);
    printf("%u\n", s.bool8);
    printf("0x%02X\n", s._8bit);
    printf("0x%04X\n", s._16bit);
    printf("0x%08X\n", s._32bit);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
8
1
0
0
0
1
1
0
1
0xAB
0xF194
0xDEC3B3A2
```

Note, my machine is little-endian and does not include padding in `myStruct`.  This code is not portable.

Comment: The idea of OPs question was to have data not on byte boundaries.

Comment: do you know if memcpy or for loop is faster for a large data buffer? The actual buffer I am working with is 233 bytes.

Comment: @HV16 Yes, but I'm intentionally doing it in the same manner as your question.

Comment: @FiddlingBits I notice that the order of the 1-bit members is reversed. It also does the same thing on my system. Is this because the compiler places the first defined bit at the least significant bit? Is there any way to tell it to place these bits in the order that we define?

Comment: @HV16 I'm not sure if it's because we have little endian computers or not.  I was surprised about that too.

Comment: @FiddlingBits to my understanding, endianness only affects byte level. I believe this bit-field placement is up to the compiler.